# Compiler error with SFINAE with VS2013 but not in VS2010

Tags: templates, c++11, visual-studio-2013, sfinae

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <tuple>
    #include <functional>
    #include <boost/utility/declval.hpp>

    class cBuffer
    {};

    template<typename T>
    class cBufferT : public cBuffer
    {};

    template <typename T, typename FUNC>
    struct cCallbackChecker
    {
        struct HasNoParam
        {
            template <typename U>
            static auto test(U *x, FUNC i_callback) -> decltype((x->*i_callback)(), char());

            template <typename U>
            static auto test(...) -> int;

            enum
            {
                value = sizeof(test<T>(0, 0)) == 1
            };
        };
        struct HasParam
        {
            template <typename U>
            static auto test(U *x, FUNC i_callback) -> decltype((x->*i_callback)(std::declval<cBuffer *>()), char());

            template <typename U>
            static auto test(...) -> int;

            enum
            {
                value = sizeof(test<T>(0, 0)) == 1
            };
        };
    };

template<typename FUNC, typename STATION>
void bindCallback(STATION *i_station, typename std::enable_if<cCallbackChecker<STATION, FUNC>::HasNoParam::value, FUNC>::type i_callback)
{
}
template<typename FUNC, typename STATION>
void bindCallback(STATION *i_station, typename std::enable_if<cCallbackChecker<STATION, FUNC>::HasParam::value, FUNC>::type i_callback)
{
}
template<typename FUNC, typename STATION>
void test(STATION *i_station, FUNC i_callback)
{
    bindCallback<FUNC, STATION>(i_station, i_callback);
}

struct Test
{
//  void f(cBuffer *); //works
    void f(cBufferT<int> *); // not works
    {}
};
struct Test2
{
    void f()
    {}
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    auto b = boost::declval<int>();
    Test t;
    test(&t, &Test::f);
    Test2 t2;
    test(&t2, &Test2::f);
}
```

This code does not compile with VS2013 but does in VS2010.

VS2013 issues:

> `C2770: invalid explicit template argument(s) for 'void bindCallback.`

So, does anybody has an idea why this error occurs and what to do in that case. I want to check if a member function does with the given signature does exist.

I now got it to work with the no parameter case. But now I want to also support a single parameter of type `cBuffer *`. In VS2010 this code works. In VS2013 it does not.

Comment: You need to ask a question or your post is liable to be closed.

Comment: Unrelated: both overloads of `HasNoParam::test` return `int`, so `value` will only ever be `true` on platforms where `int` and `char` are the same size. I assume you meant for one overload to return `char` - in which case they will be indistinguishable on platforms where `int` and `char` are the same size ;)

Comment: Microsoft calls this failure to implement C++ "lack of Expression SFINAE support".